# Getting the average color of frames in a video

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

End goal: Get the average colour of each frame in a video.

My plan so far is this:

1. Export the frames of the video as individual images.
2. Batch process the images to resize them as 1px x 1px as I believe this will provide the average colour.
3. Get the RGB value of that one pixel and record it as text.

Where I'm stuck is step 3. I've no idea how one would go about this programmatically.

I only need to do this once or twice, so it doesn't need to be completely automatic, I'm just keen to avoid copy pasting colour values manually.

EDIT: The first two steps don't require any programming so I am pretty open to using whatever language your solution requires. My forte is PHP, and this is for an Arduino project, so C-like languages are fine, but whatever will get the job done. I use a Mac but Windows or Linux also not a problem either.

Comment: what language are you using to write your code?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are doing something with image processing, I assume you are doing this in matlab.

So you can read the image first:

```
A = imread('filename.jpg');
```

To get the Red color you can use:

```
A(1,1,1);
```

To get Green and Blue just change the index to 2 and 3 respectively in the third column.